# Stfalcon Chatkit Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, chat

First and foremost I will appreciate if any one have any tutorial or walkthrough on how to implement chatkit android library by stfalcon.
My challenges are: How do I differentiate between the sender and the receiver if their is only one adapter and the sender or receiver is determined from there???

```
  messagesList = (MessagesList) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
        adapter = new MessagesListAdapter(this.senderId, null);
        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Secondly can I have an explanation on the Model part? The UserModel is a bit confusing to me!

```
public class Message implements IMessage {
    public String text;
    public String id;
    public Date createdAt;
    public UserModel author = new UserModel();


    public Message(String text, String id, Date createdAt) {
        this.text = text;
        this.id = id;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public UserModel getUser() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
}
```

Pls don't be offended by my question!!! just a bit hard implementing this good library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your MessagesListAdapter, you specify the senderId, which is the current user.
In the IMessage interface, you need to implement the IUser interface (UserModel in your example). In this interface, you need to fill the user Id getter.

The library knows if you receive or send a message thanks to that variable inside the IMessage interface. If the author Id is yours, you are the sender. Otherwise, you are the receiver.

Is that clear ? :)

Comment: Thank you, I already created the whole layouts and implemented them manually. No longer using the library but thanks by the way.